# Hamiltonian circuit in a Hamming graph

Tags: graph-theory

The problem is exactly what I have asked here:

[Showing that a particular graph is Hamiltonian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43596/showing-that-a-particular-graph-is-hamiltonian)

> Let $Q:=\{1,2,\ldots, q\}$. Let $G$ be a graph with the elements of
>   $Q^n$ as vertices and an edge between $(a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_n)$ and
>   $(b_1,b_2,\ldots, b_n)$ if and only if $a_i\ne b_i$ for exactly one
>   value of $i$. Show that $G$ is Hamiltonian.

My question is whether my partial solution (given below) is correct and to complete the solution on similar lines?

> We induct on $n$. For $n=1$, the graph $K_q$ is clearly Hamiltonian.
>   Assume that for $n-1$ the corresponding graph on $Q^{n-1}$ vertices
>   has a Hamiltonian circuit $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{q^{n-1}},x_1$. Now
>   consider the graph $G$ and consider the case when $q$ is even.
>
> The Hamiltonian circuit is:
>   $$1x_1,2x_1,\ldots,qx_1,qx_2,(q-1)x_2,\ldots,1x_2,1x_3,2x_3,\ldots,1x_{q^{n-1}},1x_1.$$

Edit: I could not follow Henning Makholm's hint given below, but the following solution struck me as more simple. Is it correct?

> We induct on $n$. For $n=1$, the graph $K_q$ is clearly Hamiltonian.
>   Assume that for $n-1$ the corresponding graph on $Q^{n-1}$ vertices
>   has a Hamiltonian circuit $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{q^{n-1}},x_1$. Now
>   consider the following Hamiltonian circuit to complete the proof:
>
> $$1x_1,1x_2,\ldots,1x_{q^{n-1}-1},2x_{q^{n-1}-1},x_{q^{n-1}-2},\ldots,2x_1,3x_1,\ldots,y,qx_{q^{n-1}},(q-1)x_{q^{n-1}},\ldots,1x_{q^{n-1}},1x_1$$
>   where $y=qx_1$ or $y=qx_{q^{n-1}-1}$ depending on whether $q$ is even or odd respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that looks like it will work.

In order to remove the dependency on $q$ being even, you can modify your solution such that next-to-last layer ends at an index *between* $1$ and $q-1$, which will allow the *last* layer to end at index $1$ no matter whether it's odd or even.

(This requires $q\ge 3$, but $q=2$ can be handled by your existing solution for even $q$).