# List the subsets of $\left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9\right\}$

Tags: graph-theory, problem-solving

Consider the set $S = \left\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9\right\}$. Prove that you can make a list of all of 256 subsets
of $S$ so that each subset occurs exactly once, the empty set is first in the list, and each subset
in the list after the first is obtained by either adding one element to the preceding subset or
deleting one element from the preceding subset.

I tried to solve this question using graph theory, but so far I haven't gotten any result. Can you find any pattern from the solution? I have tried smaller problems like 4 and 5 elements, but still didn't get any sense.

Comment: It is definitely graph theory, you need to find a Hamiltonian path in a suitably defined graph.

Comment: It is a well-known combinatorial design called a [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) (named after Frank Gray).  The topic of generating such lists recursively has been discussed previously, both here and on StackOverflow.  I'll look for some links.

Comment: Here is a previous Question that ties together creating subsets with the Hamiltonian path and Gray code subjects: [Showing that a particular graph is Hamiltonian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43596/showing-that-a-particular-graph-is-hamiltonian)

Comment: Of treatments at StackOverflow that exploit (rather than *avoiding*) recursion, this one is pretty typical: [Gray Code using recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34746773/gray-code-using-recursion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple proof is by induction on the number of elements of $S$.  For a one element set $\{1\}$ you can do $\emptyset, \{1\}$.  Now suppose you can do it with $k$ elements in $S$.  We can create such a list for $k+1$ elements by making the list for the first $k$ elements in $S$, then adding the $k+1^{st}$ element to the last subset, then reversing the original list with $k+1$ added to each one.  Continuing our example, we have the answer for $k=1$, then our list for $k=2$ is $\emptyset, \{1\}, \{1,2\}, \{2\}$